# alertDialog listener button provides incorrect output android

Tags: android, methods, android-alertdialog

Ok I have a dialog box that comes up when a counter hits 0. The box has two options, ok, and reset. When reset is clicked it is supposed to reset the counters. Currently it does not reset the counter until another button is clicked(any of the buttons that manipulate the counter). I want it to reset from the alert Dialog like I have tried below. Please advise

```
AlertDialog.Builder game = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    game.setMessage(text).setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
{
                    // do things when the user clicks ok.
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Reset", new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
       reset();
        dialog.cancel();
   }


 });
    AlertDialog alert = game.create();

    // Show the dialog box.
    alert.show();
}
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
void reset() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    display.setText(String.valueOf(20));
    lifep2.setText(String.valueOf(20));

}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `counter` and `counter1` values against the view(s) that visualize it? Just changing the value of two variables doesn't result in the UI being updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What component the counter is assigned for?

If `textView` are assigned to the counter you should consider setting the `textView` to counter value like:

`your-textView.setText(String.valueOf(counter1));`

Comment: I updated my code to what I think you were saying it should be. The issue is that now when I hit reset it resets both values to 20 like I want, but when I use one of the buttons to add or subtract static values of 1 or 5, it sets the counter to 0 plus the value again. Example is that I hit reset, both values go back to 20, then I hit plus 5 and instead of the counter now being 25, it sets to only 5.

Comment: I got it working. I deleted the counter1=20 when I added your code so the text was being reset but not the counter. Thank you for your help!